# PowerShell Start-ScheduledTasks with Wildcard Folder

Tags: powershell

For Start-Scheduled tasks if I have multiple folders like Test1, Test2, Test3, ... if I have the same ScheduledTask name ie. Run, how can I make Powershell start-scheduledTask run each of those scheduled tasks?

I tried

`Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName '\Microsoft\*\Run'`

but that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Run" |Start-ScheduledTask
```